# Battery indicator has disappeared from Gnome panel

Tags: indicator, battery

I'm using Gnome Flashback (still the best!) on Ubuntu 14.04. In the Indicator app, it used to always show the battery level indicator. Now, it's missing entirely:

[image: no battery indicator]

I've looked in the power settings to make sure it's set to show no matter what:

[image: power settings]

I assume "When battery is present" means "show the battery indicator whether charging or plugged in or whatever, just as long as the physical battery is in the laptop." I also tried the other option, "When battery is charging or in use", but that doesn:t make a difference.

The battery indicator was there consistently since upgrading to 14.04 a month ago, and has only started to be shy about appearing within maybe the last few days. So far as I know, I haven't done anything to alter any settings regarding power or indicators or applets that would have any impact on this.

Why is my power indicator missing, and how do I get it back?

Comment: Just to check (since your settings seem to be correct) from the command line: What is the output of `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.power icon-policy`? It should be "present". If it is not, the question is why it does not match the settings GUI.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, thank you for replying. The output of the command you provide is `'present'`.

Comment: Could you confirm if it's running `ps ax | grep indicator-power` ? Also you nay try `dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/power/` then `pkill -f indicator-power`

Comment: @Sneetsher, thank you for responding. The output of the `grep` command was only `2915 pts/3    R+     0:00 grep indicator-power`, so it seems the power indicator is not running. The other commands had no effect.

Comment: So locate where is it, `sudo updatedb; locate -r indicator-power-service$` Then run it directly from terminal, example: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service` please report any output

Comment: @Sneetsher, following the command in your last comment, running indicator-power-service command directly in the command line, has now resulted in the indicator being visible in my Gnome Panel. `:)`. There was no other output. Now... can I make this permanent? If I close the terminal window, the indicator disappears.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Note: Try steps 4/5 first, it may be fixed with 1st hit.**

Below the extended instruction to debug the problem with the indicator.

1. Check if `indicator-power-service` is running:

   ```
   ps ax | grep indicator-power
   ```
2. If it's running, try reset its settings then restart it:

   ```
   dconf reset -f /com/canonical/indicator/power/
   pkill -f indicator-power-service
   ```

   No success, locate it then try it from terminal (looking for any errors in output):

   ```
   sudo updatedb; locate -r indicator-power-service$
   ```

   My system is 64bit, So:

   ```
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
   ```

   If it works with command, then some thing wrong with its autostart.
3. As it was checked, it isn't running on start up. Verify the existence of:

   `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/indicator-power.conf`

   ```
   description "Indicator Power Backend"

   # Want to move to indicator-services-[start|end], but that's not all
   # there yet.  Use the signals that exist today for now.

   start on indicators-loaded or indicator-services-start
   stop on desktop-end or indicator-services-end

   respawn

   exec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
   ```

   `/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-power.desktop`

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=Indicator Power
   Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
   NotShowIn=Unity;
   NoDisplay=true
   StartupNotify=false
   Terminal=false
   ```
4. This works for me with a fresh Ubuntu 14.04, Modifing `indicator-power.desktop` for autostart conditions similar to the other indicators. (*Submitted bug report* [**lp#1330302**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1330302))

   `sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-power.desktop`

   Remove:

   ```
   NotShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   Replace it with:

   ```
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;XFCE;GNOME;
   AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome
   ```
5. Logout/Login

---

Well if it didn't work:

1. Try purge it then reinstall it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge indicator-power
   sudo apt-get install indicator-power
   ```

   Reboot, Check again
2. No success, as workaround you can run it this way (you may close terminal after this):

   ```
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service & disown $!
   ```

   `&` run it in background
   `disown $!` command to detach a process for current terminal, `$!` variable that hold PID of last process run in background

   Or better if add it to user startup applications, see [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have both the files you mention in point 3, and they have the exact same contents as you. I can successfully run the command you offer and close a terminal window, but after I reboot, the power indicator is not there. I'd like to not have to run that command every time I restart. I seem to have all the power indicator components, but it does not automatically start. Is there a way I can get it to be there every time I start my computer?

Comment: I tried the `cp` command, and rebooted, but, unfortunately, my battery indicator did not appear after logging in.

Comment: Logging in as a guest session, the battery indicator is not there. I could add the command to the startup commands list, but is that a workaround? It seems that the battery indicator should already be displaying without having to explcitly run it in the startup applications.

Comment: Okay, I've added the command to my list of startup applications for now, though I hesitate to consider the matter closed. It would be nice to have a solution that addressed the issue of why it was my battery indicator disappeared in the first place.

Comment: You may have already tried or checked this, but if you are running the Unity Tweak Tool there is a selection for Panel that includes power indicator visiblility.

Comment: @DaveMG, any error in `~/.cache/upstart/unity-panel-service.log` ?

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I looked for that log, but `No such file or directory`. Also, I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but, as mentioned in the question, I'm not using Unity, I'm on Gnome Flashback.

Comment: @DaveMG, Yep, I forgot that. I have updated answer with mod to .desktop file, which works for me in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The updated `.desktop` edit that you suggest in step 4 solved it. Nice work! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are great. After the first two steps, my power indicator came back :)

Comment: Thanks, for me it's enough to run `pkill -f indicator-power-service
` to make it reappear.

Answer (score 4):

***(1)***

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

change `icon-policy` to `present`. This might help you.

[image]

***(2)***

If first one do not work you can try to install `indicator-power` by `sudo apt-get install indicator-power`. If `indicator-power` is already install then uninstall it and then reinstall. This might get the power indicator back on the panel. Have fun.

Comment: Thank you for this response. `icon-policy` was already set to `present`. I also have `show-percentage` and `show-time` checked on.

Comment: I tried the second suggestion of reinstalling the package, but it does not seem to have changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using such themes as masalla, they somehow make the icons disappear or make the battery status to display incorrectly. I would suggest switching to the default theme or use a different theme. At least that was the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a wireless mouse plugged in it may be hiding underneath of it, just click the mouse and it should be in that pop-up menu,