# Battery indicator disappears on connecting the power

Tags: gnome, power-management, indicator, battery

I removed Unity and installed Gnome on Ubuntu 14.04. Now the battery indicator disappears on connecting power. The indicator-power-service appears to be there but it isn't working.
On running it from terminal

```
$ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service & disown $!
```

It says:

> Indicator-Power-Message: exiting: service couldn't acquire or lost
>   ownership of busname

How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems to me a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/473784/battery-indicator-has-disappeared-from-gnome-panel . Could you try the accepted answer.

Comment: I have tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: Check System *Settings > Power > Show battery status in the menu bar* . It should be *When battery is present* so the indicator will be always visible.

Comment: It is already so.

Comment: which gnome mode you are using?

Comment: Normal shell mode