# Indicator-Power-Message: exiting: service couldn't acquire or lost ownership of busname

Tags: power-management, indicator, battery, macbook

Sometimes I see my battery indicator and sometimes I don't. I've attempted every fix in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473784/battery-indicator-has-disappeared-from-gnome-panel) with no results. I might have found the source of the problem, though. When I run

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
```

I get the output

```
Indicator-Power-Message: exiting: service couldn't acquire or lost ownership of busname
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on a Macbook Pro 8,3

Answer (score 0):

This seems a confirmed bug for Ubuntu . Please check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1257251?comments=all

Try to reinstall it:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-power
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem.