# mate-power-manager not showing battery tray icon after ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: icons, power-management, battery, mate

After upgrading to 18.04, the battery tray icon from mate-power-manager simply disappeared

As everyone can imagine, a tray icon showing the battery load level is extremely important on laptops

How can i log this issue and share information here? What else should i also try, and which alternate lightweight tools should i try that also shows a battery tray icon?

(i’m mostly using AwesomeWM, and replaced most of the Gnome3 tools with their Mate equivalents, so i would struggle a lot to use gnome-power-manager, specially if it will force me to have those whole Gnome3-related packages installed as dependency)

Thanks in advance!

```
guest@macbookair:~$ mate-power-manager 

(mate-power-manager:574): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:35:25.674: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:51:14: not a number

(mate-power-manager:574): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:35:25.674: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:51:14: Expected a string.

(mate-power-manager:574): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:35:25.675: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:129:14: not a number

(mate-power-manager:574): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:35:25.675: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:129:14: Expected a string.

(mate-power-manager:574): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:35:25.679: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:845:21: not a number

(mate-power-manager:574): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:35:25.679: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:845:21: Expected a string.
TI:08:35:25 TH:0x55ef43ac5560   FI:gpm-main.c   FN:main,246
 - Power Manager is already running in this session.
Traceback:
    mate-power-manager(+0x19dff) [0x55ef433f0dff]
    mate-power-manager(+0x88a8) [0x55ef433df8a8]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f2879566b97]
    mate-power-manager(+0x8b0a) [0x55ef433dfb0a]
guest@macbookair:~$
```

Comment: You should report bug to https://bugs.launchpad.net with `apport-bug mate-power-manager`, not here. On my Asustek laptop icon is in place.

Comment: Also it seems that `mate-power-manager` should not launch as you tried. It started automatically (see *Power Manager is already running in this session* in your question). On both 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS I have battery icon in tray and the same message if I start MATE Power Manager from terminal. So there is no problem here. User-oriented GUIs have other names - `mate-power-statistics` and `mate-power-preferences`. If you need traditional desktop experience you can install MATE DE with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop`.

Comment: the problem is that, not only i have no idea where from mate-power-manager got “already” running (from startupitems.sh script, that runs always when AwesomeWM starts ), as i have no idea why the icon tray is not being displayed - http://xomf.com/csdnh - and you know where from can we find documentation explaining how apport-bug mate-power-manager at bugs.launchpad.net works? thanks!

Comment: This solved it for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031950/can-t-get-network-applet-back-in-ubuntu-mate-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I hit this too.  In my case the power manager was missing.  It didn't show up in the settings.  'sudo apt-get install mate-power-manager-common' fixed this then you have to go into the settings->power-manager-preferences->on-battery-power and select.  I also did several things on the indicator-power-service to get it working but installing the power manager may have fixed this too. [Look at this response on the power indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473784/battery-indicator-has-disappeared-from-gnome-panel) for help on that.  Where he says "OnlyShowIn=Unity;XFCE;GNOME;" you need to add "MATE;" to get the battery indicator to show up.